# Symfony2 - The EntityManager is closed

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I made yesterday a small change field type an entity of my project.

The field was of type "string" and changed to "integer".

In my localhost I have not thrown any errors Symfony2 logs, either in the test environment.

But after making the deployment to the production server (having cleared cache and run the schema: update) has begun to skip this error in the log of production:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "The EntityManager is closed." at /var/customers/webs/estreams/estreams.tv/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php line 129

This is the field that i changed:

From

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="string", lenght=5)
```

To

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
```

Comment: Did you create a specific migration?

Comment: Specific migration? Dont understund. :(

Comment: Have a look to http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Comment: Ive doesnt any migration

Comment: Have a look to your prod database, and verifiy if the type of `level` column is `int`.

Comment: First backup everything or make a test environment then update all the bundles with "composer update"